# Azure resources created using custom provider not showing on azure portal

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-custom-providers

I created an Azure custom provider by following the documentation in the link below:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/

I am able to successfully create resources for the types defined in the custom provider using ARM templates. However, I do not see those resources on the azure portal under the specific resource group.

Is this behavior expected?

Answer (score 0):

- I have deployed the custom provider in azure portal using ARM template by following below steps
- Open azure portal and search for **custom deployment** as below

[image]

- Taken reference from [Microsoft Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/custom-providers/create-custom-provider?tabs=azure-cli)
- After opening custom deployment, i have used the below code and then click on **save**

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2019-04-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
  "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
  "parameters": {
        "funcName": {
            "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[uniqueString(resourceGroup().id)]",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "The unique name of the function application"
      }
        },
    "storageName": {
            "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "[concat('store', uniquestring(resourceGroup().id))]",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "The unique name of the storage account."
      }
        },
    "location": {
            "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "eastus",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "The location for the resources."
      }
        },
    "zipFileBlobUri": {
            "type": "string",
      "defaultValue": "https://github.com/Azure/azure-docs-json-samples/blob/master/custom-providers/_artifacts/functionpackage.zip?raw=true",
      "metadata": {
                "description": "The URI to the uploaded function zip file"
      }
        }
    },
  "resources": [
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites",
      "apiVersion": "2022-03-01",
      "name": "[parameters('funcName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "functionapp",
      "identity": {
            "type": "SystemAssigned"
      },
      "dependsOn": [
        "[resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "name": "[parameters('funcName')]",
        "siteConfig": {
                "appSettings": [
                  {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsDashboard",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2022-05-01').keys[0].value)]"
                  },
            {
                    "name": "AzureWebJobsStorage",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2022-05-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
                    "name": "FUNCTIONS_EXTENSION_VERSION",
              "value": "~2"
            },
            {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING",
              "value": "[concat('DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=',parameters('storageName'),';AccountKey=',listKeys(resourceId('Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts', parameters('storageName')), '2022-05-01').keys[0].value)]"
            },
            {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE",
              "value": "[toLower(parameters('funcName'))]"
            },
            {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION",
              "value": "6.5.0"
            },
            {
                    "name": "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE",
              "value": "[parameters('zipFileBlobUri')]"
            }
          ]
        },
        "clientAffinityEnabled": false,
        "reserved": false
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts",
      "apiVersion": "2022-05-01",
      "name": "[parameters('storageName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "kind": "StorageV2",
      "sku": {
            "name": "Standard_LRS"
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders",
      "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
      "name": "[parameters('funcName')]",
      "location": "[parameters('location')]",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/',parameters('funcName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "actions": [
              {
                "name": "ping",
            "routingType": "Proxy",
            "endpoint": "[concat('https://', parameters('funcName'), '.azurewebsites.net/api/{requestPath}')]"
              }
        ],
        "resourceTypes": [
          {
                "name": "users",
            "routingType": "Proxy,Cache",
            "endpoint": "[concat('https://', parameters('funcName'), '.azurewebsites.net/api/{requestPath}')]"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
        "type": "Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders/users",
      "apiVersion": "2018-09-01-preview",
      "name": "[concat(parameters('funcName'), '/ana')]",
      "location": "parameters('location')",
      "dependsOn": [
        "[concat('Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders/',parameters('funcName'))]"
      ],
      "properties": {
            "FullName": "Ana Bowman",
        "Location": "Moon"
      }
    }
  ],
  "outputs": {
        "principalId": {
            "type": "string",
      "value": "[reference(concat('Microsoft.Web/sites/', parameters('funcName')), '2022-03-01', 'Full').identity.principalId]"
        }
    }
}
```

- Fill the following details like **Subscription id**, **resource group**, **location** and click on **review+create**

[image]

- After deploying into the azure portal, we will get below

[image]

- After deploying it to **azure poral** Goto azure portal and click on your **resource group** and click on the check box you will find as below

[image]

Comment: Yes, the custom provider shows in the portal. I am referring to a resource created using the custom provider. Have you tried that?

Comment: I didn't get exactly what you are saying. can you tell me more about it ?

Comment: As per your ARM template deployment, where is the 'Microsoft.CustomProviders/resourceProviders/users' resource showing on the portal?

Comment: Please follow the steps so you can get an idea what capability's that custom provider has Open azure portal => Search for subscription as shown [image1](https://i.imgur.com/X3WDRFx.png) => Select subscription name => follow the steps shown in [image2](https://i.imgur.com/pvLKtME.png), AFAIK, the custom provider as the capability as shown in [Image3](https://i.imgur.com/ohBWEi5.png) so it's not possible to track the custom provider in a particular resource Group (or) Subscription